# windows C++ Ldap build error _imp__ldap_init()

Tags: c++, windows, ldap

I am building a C++ program that queries against Active Directory using (Apache Directory studio) LDAP . Iam doing it with codeblocks IDE and windows 10. I have the following code sample from the program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<winldap.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    LDAP* testLdapConnection = NULL;
    ULONG version = LDAP_VERSION1;
    ULONG connectionSuccess = 0;
    testLdapConnection = ldap_initA("localhost",389);
    if(testLdapConnection==NULL){
        cout<<"connection Failed";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Success";
    }

}
```

When I try to build this sample in codeblocks, the build fails and the line with ldap_init() is underlined in red. When I hover the mouse over the error, it says "Undefined reference to _imp__ldap_initA()."

Answer (score 1):

You have to add Wldap32.lib to list of linked libraries in your project.

Comment: I did but still getting error "cannot find -lWldap32.Lib"

Comment: You have strange prefix "-I" before library name Wldap32.Lib. Are you sure you're adding it to Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies in project settings?

Comment: I am adding it to linker.